# Searching with Multiple (Parallel) Criteria on Custom Fields?

Tags: custom-field, search, query, customization

I'm just an basic Wordpress user. I need to make search box with **multiple criteria** inputs (multiple conditions) to search **inside various Custom Fields**.

For example including following **Custom Fields**:

Color: ***_*___**
Size: **__*_*_**
Price: ***_*__**
Condition: **__*_***
Discount %: ***_*__**
Hit Count: **__*_***

User may input **1 or more** fileds.
**Result should be filtered for multiple input also.**
For example: `Price: ____100___` and `Condition: ____Fair____`
So, how can i handle this multiple conditions in Query?

It is **ok for every single inputs**.
But, problem with more then 1.
I'm confusing how to write query **for multiple criteria** (in former way).

A simple sample please.

Comment: Try this http://matthewaprice.com/search-multiple-custom-fields-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

have a look at WP_Query(); and use meta_query / tax_query arguments

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'color',
            'value' => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```